# Ubuntu Server 16.10 not Responding to Neighbor Solicitation (IPv6)

Tags: networking, server, ipv6

I'm pinging from one Ubuntu box to another. The Ubuntu box not cooperating has these addresses:

`2000::1:215:5dff:fe091:229/64` & `fe80::215:5dff:fe01:299/64`

The upstream router is sending out a neighbor solicitation for the first of those addresses. A `tcpdump` confirms ubuntu is receiving those solicitations for its own address however it is not responding. What am I missing?

`ipconfig` / `tcpdump` output:

```
husband@ipv6-client:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:01:02:29
          inet6 addr: 2000::1:215:5dff:fe01:229/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe01:229/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7475 errors:0 dropped:628 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1247888 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1112316 (1.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:355015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:355015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:26412928 (26.4 MB)  TX bytes:26412928 (26.4 MB)

husband@ipv6-client:~$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:07:08.230956 IP6 fe80::c609:39ff:fee5:10 > ff02::1:ff01:299: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2000::1:215:5dff:fe01:299, length 32
18:07:09.226625 IP6 fe80::c609:39ff:fee5:10 > ff02::1:ff01:299: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has 2000::1:215:5dff:fe01:299, length 32
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

`ip6tables` / `ip -6 route` output:

```
husband@ipv6-client:~$ sudo ip6tables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
husband@ipv6-client:~$ ip -6 route
2000:0:0:1::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 2591898sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via fe80::c609:39ff:fee5:10 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1698sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

Comment: Please include more information like your config file contents, your IPv6 routing table and ip6tables settings. Please provide them as text in this question. Providing important information as images which are hosted elsewhere makes it harder to read your question and can result in your question making no sense if in the future the images disappear.

Comment: That image is linked via the built in image button part of the posting mechanism. It is not hosted elsewhere. Will provide additional info.

Edit: It appears Ubuntu uses imgur for hosting its images, but I used the built in mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok everyone. Strap yourselves in because you are about to go on the IPv6 ride of your lives. Are you ready? Ok. Here we go.

I pinged the wrong address by one digit. Last octet is 229 not 299.

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer to close the question.